# How to set DateTime format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, datetime

Hello I have a one column in `Oracle` `LASTFETCHAT` and it's type is `DATE` the same column I have in `MySQL` and it's datatype is `DATETIME` the prob is while I am inserting recorde in Oracle for `LASTFETCHAT` with the value of `12-JUL-11 10.20.10` it will successfully inserted but in `MySQL` it will give me error like **datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column**

Actully I am Export Dates from Oracle to CSV and Import it on MySQL.

Comment: Why don't you export the data in the correct format then?  Or tell your import tool which format your export has? How do you export and import the data anyway which tools are you using?

Comment: I am using inbuilt Oracle Tool Export and import